# Command Line MySQL dump with hyphen in database name

Tags: mysql

I am looking to ignore certain tables during mysql dump do to large size.

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump -u$DBUSER -p$DBPWD $IGNORETABLES --databases $db | gzip > "$OUTPUTDIR/db-currentdate.sql.gz"
```

I want to ignore tables using --ignore-table=database.table but my database has a hyphen in the name which breaks.  Is there a way to escape the database name with the hyphen.  Please remember I am doing this via command line and not php (that would be to easy!)

The IGNORETABLES variable will be built from a table and compared against before final backup.

I have it working on tables within database without hyphen.  As soon as I put in one with hyphen it gives all tables.  **Please note that database naming convention was a result of parallels control panel which used (domain_com_-_database)

Answer (score 3):

You need to put back ticks arround your database name `db-name`

e.g.

mysqldump 'db-name' > db-name.sql

Answer (score 0):

Which version of MySQL are you using? This seems to work fine for me with 5.5.40.

I tried it with:

```
CREATE DATABASE `domain_com_-_database`;
USE `domain_com_-_database`;
CREATE TABLE a (i INT);
CREATE TABLE b (i INT);
```

And then:

```
mysqldump --ignore-table=domain_com_-_database.b --databases domain_com_-_database
```

The output only contains table a, no b.

(Sorry, I know I should have posted this as a comment, but I don't have the reputation to do that.)

Answer (score 0):

I am actually running the command as a shell script.  Not via mysql command line.  Basically I only get a single line to submit at a time and the "-" breaks (doesn't ignore)

MySQL Version 5.5.30